# How the builtin Python's next function works as used in the Gunicorn server

Tags: python, iterator, gunicorn, iterable, built-in

The following is the code cross section from `gunicorn.workers.sync.SyncWorker` class `self.handle` method:

```py
def handle(self, listener, client, addr):
        req = None
        try:
            if self.cfg.is_ssl:
                client = sock.ssl_wrap_socket(client, self.cfg)
            parser = http.RequestParser(self.cfg, client, addr)
            req = next(parser)
            self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
```

The above method executes the line: `parser = http.RequestParser(self.cfg, client, addr)` which returns a `gunicorn.http.parser.RequestParser` object that inherits from `gunicorn.http.parser.Parser` which is given as follows:

```py
class Parser(object):

    mesg_class = None

    def __init__(self, cfg, source, source_addr):
        self.cfg = cfg
        if hasattr(source, "recv"):
            self.unreader = SocketUnreader(source)
        else:
            self.unreader = IterUnreader(source)
        self.mesg = None
        self.source_addr = source_addr

        # request counter (for keepalive connetions)
        self.req_count = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        # Stop if HTTP dictates a stop.
        if self.mesg and self.mesg.should_close():
            raise StopIteration()

        # Discard any unread body of the previous message
        if self.mesg:
            data = self.mesg.body.read(8192)
            while data:
                data = self.mesg.body.read(8192)

        # Parse the next request
        self.req_count += 1
        self.mesg = self.mesg_class(self.cfg, self.unreader, self.source_addr, self.req_count)
        if not self.mesg:
            raise StopIteration()
        return self.mesg

    next = __next__
```

The object `gunicorn.http.parser.Parser` above defines both `self.__iter__` and `self__next__` special methods, a protocol for `iterables` and `iterators`. However, `parser`, the local variable which holds the returned object, defined in the method `self.handle` is an instance of  `gunicorn.http.parser.RequestParser`, not an `iterator`, as confirmed by output from `pdb` (see stracktrace below) python debugger: `<class 'gunicorn.http.parser.RequestParser'>`. Following the returned object which has been assigned to `parser`, the method executes the line: `req = next(parser)`, and it is passed `parser` as its argument.

###### Question:

Shouldn't the builtin function `next()` accepts the first argument as an iterator? `parser` is not an `iterator` it is, but an instance of class `gunicorn.http.parser.RequestParser`. The following is `next()`'s documentation from Python:

```
next(iterator)
next(iterator, default)
Retrieve the next item from the iterator by calling its __next__() method. If default is given, it is returned if the iterator is exhausted, otherwise StopIteration is raised.
```

I've run the `pdb` to produce the stacktrace to confirm what actually happens when the line: `req=next(parser)` executes. It drops into the method `self.__next__` of `gunicorn.http.parser.Parser`. The method `self.__iter__`, which should return an `iterator`, is not called at all, and actually I commented it out of the code and the code works with no complications. Is the method `self.__iter__` actually required after all?

##### Stacktrace:

```
/home/humbulani/django/env/bin/gunicorn(8)<module>()
-> sys.exit(run())
  /home/humbulani/django/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py(71)run()
-> WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  /home/humbulani/django/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py(264)run()
-> super().run()
  /home/humbulani/django/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py(74)run()
-> Arbiter(self).run()
  /home/humbulani/django/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py(226)run()
-> self.manage_workers()
  /home/humbulani/django/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py(602)manage_workers()
-> self.spawn_workers()
  /home/humbulani/django/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py(673)spawn_workers()
-> self.spawn_worker()
  /home/humbulani/django/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py(640)spawn_worker()
-> worker.init_process()
  /home/humbulani/django/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py(144)init_process()
-> self.run()
  /home/humbulani/django/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py(126)run()
-> self.run_for_one(timeout)
  /home/humbulani/django/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py(70)run_for_one()
-> self.accept(listener)
  /home/humbulani/django/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py(32)accept()
-> self.handle(listener, client, addr)
  /home/humbulani/django/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py(140)handle()
-> req = next(parser) # self.msg attribute
> /home/humbulani/django/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/http/parser.py(37)__next__()
-> if self.mesg and self.mesg.should_close():
```

Your response will be highly appreciated.

Comment: An iterator is just an object that has a `__next__` method; the class `Parser` defines that.

Comment: And since `Parser` has a `__next__()` method, it's instances are iterators. That's why `__iter__()` can simply return `self`.

Answer (score 0):

`next` does very little; you can imagine its implementation looks like this:

```
_sentinel = object()

def next(itr, default=_sentinel):
    try:
        return itr.__next__()
    except StopIteration:
        if default is _sentinel:
            raise
        return default
```

So `next(parser)` just calls `parser.__next__`, because `parser` is an iterator: it's an instance of a class (`Parser`) that defines `__next__`.

What `next` does *not* accept is an instance of a class that is *not* an iterator. By defining `__iter__`, `Parser` just happens to *also* (like all other iterators) be an *iterable*. You can be an iterable without being an iterator (like `list`), but not vice versa.

Comment: So, the only method required here is __next__? There’s no reason for defining __iter__? I thought __iter__ should be called first to return an iterator object for __next __ to iterate on?

Comment: Things like `map` and `filter` take *iterables*, on which they will call `iter` to get an iterator to use. `next`'s only job is to provide the next value for an iterator, not to produce an iterator in the first place.

Comment: All iterators are required (or at least strongly recommended) to be iterables as well, which is why you always see the boilerplate-y `def __iter__(self): return self` on iterators.